# I $f$ is measureable there is an ascending sequence of step functions converging pointwise to $f$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

[Book: Theodor Bröcker: Analysis II]
If $f: X \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ is measurable, then there is an ascending sequence of stepfunctions $\phi_{j}$ which converges pointwise to f, i.e. $f = sup( \phi_{j}: j \in \mathbb{N})$

The book proof is just:

Define $\phi_{j}(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
(k-1)2^{-j}, \textrm{if } (k-1)2^{-j} \leq f(x) \leq k2^{-j} , k \in \mathbb{N}, k < j2^j
\\
j, \textrm{if } f(x) \geq j
\end{matrix}\right.$ q.e.d.

The idea is depicted in the following picture:

[image]

I know that $\phi_{j}$ converges to f but my question where the measurablity of f comes into the proof. I even know that $sup_{j}  \,\phi_{j}$ is measurable if the $\phi_{j}$ are measurable, but that would just proof the opposite direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The measurability of $f$ guarantees that $M:=f^{-1}\left[\dfrac{k-1}{2^{j}},\dfrac{k}{2^{j}}\right]$ is a measurable set, or else the characteristic function $\chi_{M}$ is not measurable.

Comment: which then implies that the phi's are measurable, right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, linear combination of measurable functions is still measurable.